# Got error from devise user and wicked rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, wicked-gem

I got error from browser after sign up with email and password.

```
class UserStepsController < ApplicationController
 steps :personal

 def show
  @user = current_user
  render_wizard
 end

def update
  @user = current_user
  @user.update_attributes(user_params)
  render_wizard @user
end

def finish_wizard_path
 flash[:notice] = "You have successfully Registered With The Wizard."
 user_path(current_user)
end

private

 def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :degree_level, :role, :email,  :password )
 end

end
```

On **RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 def new
  super
 end

 def create
  super
 end

 protected
    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        '/user_steps'
    end
end
```

I allready added routes resources :user_steps, devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }

my **devise/registrations/new**

```
  <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
  <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
  <%= f.input :password, required: true %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
 </div>
 <div class="form-actions">
 <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
 </div>
 <% end %>
 <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Added personal.html.erb first name, last name and degree_level

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => wizard_path, :method => :put) do |f|%>
 <%= f.text_field :first_name  %>
 <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
 <%= f.text_field :degree_level %>
<%= f.submit 'submit', :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
<%end%>
```

user model added validates presence.
This error show after sign up with email and password

error message is **Please review the problems below:**

Comment: error msg is what?, I can see `index` action in `UserStepsController` do you have `index` view?

Comment: Did you get your code working? where did you create personal.html.erb? I mean in which folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i want add `include Wicked::Wizard`